# Spring Cloud Zuul - Access denied from auth-server when using generated jwt tokens

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to implement micro-service architecture backend api server's using **Spring Cloud Dalston.SR4** to be consumed by mobile/web applications.

**API Gateway**

Below is the configuration for Gateway micro-service

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable() //
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) //
                .and().authorizeRequests() //
                .antMatchers("/login", "/uaa/**").permitAll() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    user-service:
      path: /users/**
      service-id: user-service
      sensitive-headers: 
    uaa:
      path: /uaa/**
      strip-prefix: false
      url: ${auth-server.uri}/
      sensitive-headers: 
security:
  user:
    password: none
  basic:
    enabled: false
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: client
      client-secret: secret
      scope: openid
      access-token-uri: ${auth-server.uri}/uaa/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: ${auth-server.uri}/uaa/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      jwt:
        key-value: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhVny3DfQqdvQaPj6SJiiFfPRGH/5k3OiAXTCsmpKnL/GVKZpfFjT3LhN7xoj0DzJLTCOE94eOjIHipFzxrL00kBCZJ3HOornKDpTh17yPuqJI6DNmvJaRBbc3SVQsO0vndnDAeOBiv4euGHH97sPZYFqhmwM35PboqxeWaHrfgWcA5F8VFTp+HDPr26G4sv/UqkR1LsfRoD4gzNJswi00eWcNjeoEzy71023VECQYDytUg/wVqWOJnShWOJnCBnuzmjrtOCg6O6ecdHhVaiRI0//ZR71x2oDW5pe+kgVhhM29TH8SVRjbAFh35obN6ppcF3A7PFLf+euZTsmXMaahQIDAQAB
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**Auth-Service**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Principal getUser(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "keypass".toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("keystore"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory() //
                .withClient("client") //
                .secret("secret") //
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password") //
                .scopes("openid") //
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

}
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().disable()//
                .csrf().disable() //
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access") //
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1").password("pass1").roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

With this setup I am able to generate the access token from the uaa/oauth/token service. And I am able to use the same token for calling uaa/user service end-point, and even while directly calling other micro-service(say user-service).

But when I call the user-service through the gateway using the token generated earlier I am getting an access denied error from the auth-server.

Requested - http://localhost:8080/users/test

with header Authorization: Bearer <>

But the response from auth-server was access denied

```
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : pathInfo: both null (property equals)
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.DefaultSavedRequest            : queryString: arg1=client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=GwhNJf; arg2=client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I (property not equals)
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : saved request doesn't match
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 0F2BD608483668F10E9AD88B507858E9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/authorize?client_id=client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=6AYJ3I; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 0F2BD608483668F10E9AD88B507858E9; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@21c53585, returned: -1
2017-10-23 12:38:41.470 DEBUG 4320 --- [trace=,span=] [nio-9999-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
```

Answer (score 2):

@EnableOAuth2Sso secures all your gateway urls with SSO. I believe you'll need to disable authentication on the routes that lead to your downstream microservices, so that the Bearer token can get to them.

Try adding `/users/**` to your `permitAll()` matcher on the gateway:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and().authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/users/**", /login", "/uaa/**").permitAll();
}
```